# Alterar nome das imagens antes do upload múltiplo

Tags: php

Eu consigo enviar as imagens para o servidor, mas, quando tento alterar o nome não é enviado nada:

Código:

```
$diretorio = "../empresas/$PASTA/fotos";

$imagem = isset($_FILES['imagem']) ? $_FILES['imagem'] : FALSE;

$ext = pathinfo($_FILES['imagem']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$arqName = date("Y-m-d-h-i-s").".".$ext;

    for ($controle = 0; $controle < count($imagem['name']); $controle++){



        $destino = $diretorio."/".$imagem['name'][$controle];


        if(move_uploaded_file($arqName[$controle], $destino)){
            echo "Upload realizado com sucesso<br>"; 
        }else{
            echo "Erro ao realizar upload <br>";
        }

    }
```

Erro que aparece:

> Warning: pathinfo() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in /var/www/html/Fotos/painel/enviar-fotos-galeria.php on line 14

Linha 14:

```
$ext = pathinfo($_FILES['imagem']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver ajeitando o código desta forma

```
$diretorio = "../empresas/$PASTA/fotos";

    $imagem = isset($_FILES['imagem']) ? $_FILES['imagem'] : FALSE;
    for ($controle = 0; $controle < count($imagem['name']); $controle++){

        $extensao = pathinfo($imagem['name'][$controle]);
        $extensao = ".".$extensao['extension'];
        $imagem['name'][$controle] = time().uniqid().base_convert(mt_rand(),10,36).$extensao;

        $destino = $diretorio."/".$imagem['name'][$controle];
        if(move_uploaded_file($imagem['tmp_name'][$controle], $destino)){
            echo "Upload realizado com sucesso<br>"; 
        }else{
            echo "Erro ao realizar upload";
        }

    }
```